# Why is georeferenced TIFF location only correct if specifying "No CRS" using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I received a georeferenced TIFF. Its projection is EPSG:21096. When I add it to QGIS and specify a reference for the project, the file ends up way off the actual location (several 100km). When I set the project's CRS to "No CRS" and add the OpenStreet Map basemap (which has been used for referencing initially), the TIFF is located correctly.

How can I make sure that the TIFF is correctly located even if I specify the projection of the project explicitly?

I would like to be able to drag & drop the TIFF into other GIS software and have them align correctly there as well.

Comment: Can you run gdalinfo on your input file and share the output? Alternatively you could use something like exiftool to read the metadata.

Comment: When you say "specify a reference for the project", what exactly are you doing? And can you post your Tiff?

Comment: Please provide the X/Y min/max extent. If you assign the "correct" spatial reference and the data moves, odds are it's not correct.

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: the OpenStreet Map also has project system followed, so check both match

Answer (score 3):

What solved the problem for me now was to make sure that the .tfw file created when the .tif was referenced is in the same folder as the .tif file. With that, the .tif is correctly aligned after importing in QGIS, ArcGIS and GEE.